Construct an uncountable chain of at most countable sets, with the union uncountable.

Question: Give a construction of a family of uncountably infinite many sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ subject to:
(1) $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is totally ordered under (not necessarily proper) inclusion: $A_i\subseteq A_j$ or $A_i\supseteq A_j$ for each $i,j$. (The inclusion may not be proper).
(2) $A_i$ is at most countable for each $i$.
(3) $\cup_{i\in I} A_i$ is uncountably infinite.

The barrier which I met is that, in order that $A_i$ is countable for each $i$, it seems that there can not be too many "$\subsetneqq$", but then how can $\cup_{i\in I} A_i$ be uncountable?

You can take the countable ordinals: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal.

Related, but from a different angle: Take an uncountable set and look at the family of all chains of countable subsets. By Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal such chain. Show that the union of that chain must be uncountable.

The first comment does not assume AC though. The second comment does.

@MichaelGreinecker Thanks for your comment: Actually this is precisely how I come up with the question. This argument asserts that given any uncountable set $A$, exists such $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ with $A_i\subseteq A$ for all $i$. But I would like to know if we can explicitly give an example.

@Asigan I don’t think there is a complete explicit way to show this. Even showing that an uncountable set has a countably infinite subset requires the axiom of choice.
